# Spring MVC Controller configuration - mixing annotations and XML @PathVariable

Tags: java, configuration, spring-mvc, annotations

I am developing a web app using the Spring MVC framework (v3).

Currently I have several controller classes defined - I have created them by extending the MultiActionController and then in my web mvc XML config defined the beans and the URL mappings:

QuestionController.java:

```
public class QuestionController extends MultiActionController implements InitializingBean 
{
```

webmvc-config.XML

```
<bean id="questionController" class="com.tmm.enterprise.microblog.controller.QuestionController"></bean>
...
    <bean id="fullHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/question/**">questionController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This works fine, I define methods in my controller matching the URLs being called and everything works correctly (for example, I have a `list(..)` method, that gets correctly executed when I browse to `/question/list`).

However, for this particular controller I want to make use of the `@PathVariable` option in Spring to allow for variable URLs (e.g. i want a `details(..)` method, that when I call `/question/detail/9999` - where `9999` is a question ID the method is executed). I have tried to use this as follows:

QuestionController.java:

```
@RequestMapping("/detail/{questionId}")
public ModelAndView detail(@PathVariable("questionId") long questionId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
```

However, I get an error when I run the above and get:

> Could not find `@PathVariable` [`questionId`] in `@RequestMapping`

Has anyone come across this before? Is it ok to mix `RequestMapping` annotations with the existing XML configured URL mapping?

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to add `@RequestMapping` to a `MultiActionController`?

Comment: i only meant to say move part of uri to the top not the detail. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the comment from **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping** class, If i am reading the comment right, If you add @RequestMapping at the top of your QuestionController.java, It might resolve your problem

Annotated controllers are usually marked with the {@link Controller} stereotype
at the type level. This is not strictly necessary when {@link RequestMapping} is
applied at the type level (since such a handler usually implements the
 {@link org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller} interface). However,
 **{@link Controller}** is required for detecting **{@link RequestMapping}** annotations
 at the **method level** if {@link RequestMapping} is not present at the **type** level.

**EDIT**

You can do some thing like this, move the **/question** part of the uri to the top and leave the 
detail part at the method level

```
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController
{
  @RequestMapping("/detail/{questionId}")
  public ModelAndView detail(@PathVariable("questionId") long questionId,    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

}
```

Comment: Perfect - adding @RequestMapping to the Class did the job, thanks!